# Split with "//" and join filepaths using python

Tags: python, list

I have a few files as:

```
               file1=“C:\\temp\\IS_ModelDownload\\out” and

file2=[“mapp\\here_Model_constants.gcd”,"mapp\\here2_Model_constants.gcd"]    

  file3="glob\\here_test_constants.gcd"
```

I want to split them "//" and join them using python.Note:File2 is a list of 2 filepaths.
The desired output would be like:output: C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out\mapp\here_Model_constants.gcd C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out\mapp\here2_Model_constants.gcd C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out\glob\here_test_constants.gcd

I have tried using os. path. split("//") to split them and I'm aware of join method but I'm facing difficulty in combining altogether and retrive as desired.

Comment: You keep saying "//", but there are no forward slashes in any of your examples.  They are all backslashes.  And remember, when you use two backslashes in a Python string, there is only ONE in the string.  Thus, you don't have to split ANYTHING.  Just do `file2 = file1 + "\\mapp\\here2_model_constant.gcd"` and `file3 = file1 + "\\glob\\here_test_constants.gcd"`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have everything you need:

```
file1 = "C:\\temp\\IS_ModelDownload\\out"
file2 = ["mapp\\here_Model_constants.gcd","mapp\\here2_Model_constants.gcd"]  
file3 = "glob\\here_test_constants.gcd"

import os
print(os.path.join(file1,file2[0]))
print(os.path.join(file1,file2[1]))
print(os.path.join(file1,file3))
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out\mapp\here_Model_constants.gcd
C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out\mapp\here2_Model_constants.gcd
C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out\glob\here_test_constants.gcd
```

Remember, although we have to USE two backslashes when we create a string constant, the resulting string only has ONE backslash in it.  So:

```
print( len("a\\b") )
```

That prints 3.  This is a KEY point to understand working with text in Python.

As an alternative, you can use "raw" strings, which tell Python not to do that interpolation.  For example, this produces the same output:

```
file1 = r"C:\temp\IS_ModelDownload\out"
file2 = [r"mapp\here_Model_constants.gcd",r"mapp\here2_Model_constants.gcd"]  
file3 = r"glob\here_test_constants.gcd"

import os
print(os.path.join(file1,file2[0]))
print(os.path.join(file1,file2[1]))
print(os.path.join(file1,file3))
```

Also, as a side note, several of your strings above are using "special" quote marks like you would use in a word processing app, where the opening quotes and the closing quotes face different directions.  Those are not valid Python syntax.  You can't use an application like Word to edit your Python code.

Comment: "That prints 3. This is a KEY point to understand working with text in Python." -- and a lot of other languages, too. C++, C#, Java, ...